# GAS データがある最終行取得したい

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

GASを使ってスプレッドシートのデータがある最終行または最終カラムを取得したいです。

前まではスプレッドシートのデータがある最終行までのデータは下記のコードで取得できていたのですが、シート数が何枚にもなり下記の(変更後)にコードを変更しました。
そしたら`var row = sheet.getLastRow();`をデバックで見てみたらデータではなくセルの最終行のデータが取得されてしましました。

[Google Apps Script - スプレッドシートで各列の最終行を求めるScript](http://code-ur-life.blogspot.com/2014/03/google-apps-script-script.html)

上記サイトなどを見てみたのですが私がやりたい、データがある最終行までのデータを取得するやり方がわかりません。

なぜデータを取得したいかというとデータを取得してそのデータをforEachで回したいからです。

初心者なので初歩的な質問または文がおかしいみたいなとこがあるかもしれませんが、分かる方がいたら教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

```
コードをここに入力// データがある最終行までのデータが取得できていたコード
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var row = sheet.getLastRow();
```

Comment: 「 **複数シートがある場合** 」の最終行を取得したい、ということであれば、この点をタイトルや本文でもう少し強調しておくといいのかなと思います。 / 「コードをここに入力」も一見すると書きかけのように見えます。質問は後からでも [編集] できますので、見直してみてください。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/181058

Comment: マルチポスト先にて、他に`row`という変数を使っていたのが判明したらしいです。

Answer (score 0):

getDataRange でデータが入っている範囲を取ってきた後に getValues を適用すれば正常にデータ取得できるかと思います。

getDataRange()
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange()

getValues()
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
rows.forEach(function (row) {
  // ループ処理
});
```